# Remove rounded corners UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been trying to do this for a while now. I just want to remove the rounded corners you can see on this picture :

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it ?

[EDIT 1 : CELL BUILDING]

I am subclassing UITableViewCell to make my own layout. And then I'm adding a background to these cells like below :

```
UIImageView* imageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 44.0)];
imageView.image = cellBackground;
cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Comment: The corners aren't rounded by default. How are you building the table and cells?

Comment: Well, I just found out it disappeared... But I can't figure out what I did to make it work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corners aren't rounded by default, just so you know.

- Do you have a background image for the cell that makes the corners
  seem rounded (most likely)?
- Is each cell actually a section of the
  tableview and there is no space between them?
- Are you testing on a
  jailbroken iPhone and you have some winterboard theme installed that
  changes the style of tableviews?

Comment: Like I said, it's gone now, but I'm not working with a jailbroken device and the cells are not sections of the tableview. So, there was probably a problem with the image, but I don't remember modifying it..

Answer (score 3):

I you need to edit the backgroundview of the corresponding cell. E.g.

```
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // or any color
cell.backgroundView = bg;
[bg release];
```